# JProfiler doesn't detect running AdoptOpenJDK 11 openJ9

Tags: jprofiler

I'm trying to profile a Java app running with AdoptOpenJDK 11 version OpenJ9.
My problem is that, when I try to attach JProfiler on my app, it doesn't detect the running instance.
I'm using the last version of JProfiler (11.1.4).
Is it compatible with this JRE?
Is there something to do/configure to make it working?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of JProfiler 11.0, attach mode is not supported for OpenJ9 JVMs. Also, attach mode is not enabled by default for OpenJ9.

When passing the `-agentpath` VM parameter as given by the integration wizards, profiling OpenJ9 JVMs is fully supported.